# Nested Loops in Common Lisp

Tags: java, loops, lisp, common-lisp, nested-loops

is it possible to use nested loops in common lisp? Im trying to convert my java code into common lisp. Im using Steel Bank Common Lisp

Heres what i want to convert

```
for(i=1; i<=59; i++){
    k=1;
    for(j=2; j<i; j++)
        if(i % (j*j) == 0)
            k=0; 
    if(k != 0)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? IIRC you can nest pretty much anything in LISP, it's just all about the parenthesis.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028497/return-from-a-nested-loop-in-common-lisp

Comment: "It's all about the parentheses" is my favorite rap song about Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

So I looked at your Algol code and figured you could make it with nested loops but I would never make the algol code like that since you are iterating `j` even after you have hit a cube.

```javascript
for(i=1; i<=59; i++){
    var k=1;
    for(j=2; j<i; j++) {
        if(i % (j*j) == 0) {
            k=0; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if( k )
       System.out.println(i);
}
```

I kept `k` since Algol cannot be nested like Lisps. In Lisp you would take the inner loop inside the `if` which removed the need for a boolean variable. I split the job into two functions. One that generates numbers from 1 to max-num into a list and one that makes the desired output string from a list. Both are testable with unit tests. The very last statement has side effects since it indeed prints the result before returning it.

```lisp
(defun generate-list (max-num)
  "generates a list of numbers from 1 to max-num
   that which is not dividable by any cube of a lower
   number greater than 1"
  (loop :for i :from 1 :upto max-num
        :if (not (loop :for j :from 2 :to i
                       :if (zerop (mod i (* j j)))
                           :do (return t))) ; inner loop terminates early :-)
        :collect i))

(defun elements-to-string (list)
  "Makes a string with all elements 
   of a list on individual lines"
  (format nil "~{~a~^~%~}" list))

(princ (elements-to-string (generate-list 59)))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of helping someone new to Lisp:

```
(loop for i from 1 upto 59
   do (let ((k 1))
        (loop for j from 2 below i
           do (when (zerop (rem i (expt j 2)))
                (setf k 0)))
        (when (not (zerop k))
          (format t "~a~%" i))))
```

However, the variable `k` should probably be a boolean (`t` or `nil`).

Comment: If you end the inner `loop` after `(setf k 0)`, the logic will match the java code (that originally was incorrectly indented).