# How to use dependent loop variables with `loop` macro in Common Lisp

Tags: loops, common-lisp

Consider the following snippet of `C` code; the actual values for `M`
and the content of `arr` don't actually matter.

```
int arr[M] = {...};

for (int i=0; i<M; ++i) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<M; ++j) {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

What would be the (idiomatic and efficient) Common Lisp analog using the `loop` macro (or if `loop` is not right tool, any other construct)?

I know that comparing array access and list access is not correct but could not come up with a better example.

One possibility I tried is the following:

```
(defvar l '(1 2 ...))

(loop :for n :on l :do
   (loop :for x :in (cdr n) :do
      ;; do something
      ))
```

But this seems rather clunky.

Please note, that other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028497/return-from-a-nested-loop-in-common-lisp) deal with ranges not with lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you actually want to compute, but I don't think it is clunky.

Example:

```
CL-USER 6 > (loop for (head . tail) on '(1 2 3 4)
                  do (loop for item in tail
                           do (print (list head item))))

(1 2) 
(1 3) 
(1 4) 
(2 3) 
(2 4) 
(3 4) 
NIL
```

If you want to keep pairs based on some test:

```
CL-USER 36 > (defun mapcan-pairs (fn list)
               (loop for (head . tail) on list
                     nconc (loop for item in tail
                                 nconc (funcall fn head item))))
MAPCAN-PAIRS

CL-USER 37 > (defun keep-pairs (test list)
               (mapcan-pairs (lambda (a b)
                               (when (funcall test a b)
                                 (list (cons a b))))
                             list))
KEEP-PAIRS

CL-USER 38 >  (keep-pairs (lambda (a b)
                             (= 13 (+ a b)))
                          '(1 2 3 7 1 4 5 6 3 5 10 15 3))
((3 . 10) (7 . 6) (3 . 10) (10 . 3))
```

Comment: Well, that was quick, thanks @Rainer Joswig. The destructuring certainly looks nicer than using `cdr`. On what I actually want to compute: assume, that there is some condition on the elements of the list (e.g. the sum is equal to 42). I want to find all pairs of values in the list that satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Aroob like `(loop :for (head . tail) :on list :nconc (loop :for item :in tail :if (= target (+ head item)) :collect (list head item)))`?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, like that; RainerJoswig has already incorporated this into his answer. I guess what I really want is something like list comprehensions. But for now,  this serves my purpose.

Comment: @Sylwester Now that I look more closely, you have a `collect` keyword in your inner `loop` whereas RainerJoswig uses `nconc` in the inner `loop`. Why is that?

Comment: @Aroob: because he has the IF in the inner LOOP, while my function is more general and the WHEN is outside. You can use the NCONC variant as a more general building block, demonstrated by my MAPCAN-PAIRS, KEEP-PAIRS functions.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Ok, I see now.